# Como Eliminar Lineas de ejes en Chart.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, frontend, charts

Como Puedo Eliminar las barras de los ejes que están señaladas con las flechas azules, llevo tiempo buscando pero no encuentro la respuesta , agradezco su ayuda :D

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Checa [este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ag2spehcL84) y [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522923/how-to-remove-the-line-rule-of-an-axis-in-chart-js).

Answer (score 0):

Pon en tu instanciación del chart

```javascript
    options: {
           scales: {
                    y: {
                        display:false
                    }
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

podrías hacerlo así:

```
scales: {
    yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
            drawBorder: false,
        }
    }]
}
```

o también:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    y: {
      grid: {
        drawBorder: false,
      }
    }
  }
}
```